# Output variables to HTML tag in reusable block

Tags: html, templates, web, playframework-2.0

I have a block of codes like this:

```
@reusableBlock(isAdmin: Boolean, value: String) = @{
    if(isAdmin){
        <a href="/admin/{value}">{value}</a>
    } else {
        <a href="/{value}">{value}</a>
    }
}
```

and if I pass some parameters:

```
<h1>@reusableBlock(true, "config")</h1>
```

I get

```
<a href=localhost:9000/admin/%7Bvalue%7D >config</a> 
instead of <a href=localhost:9000/admin/config >config</a>
```

Could you enlighten me on how to output variable to HTML tag in reusable block.

Lots of thanks.

======== EDIT =======

```
    @renderRoleButton(loggedin: Account, biz: Biz, isAdminPage: Boolean) = @{
    if(loggedin != null) {
        var isManaging = false;
        var roleText = "";
        var bizUsername = biz.username;
        for(role <- loggedin.roles) {
            if(role.restaurant.id == biz.id) {
                isManaging = true;
                roleText = role.role;
            }
        }

        if(isManaging) {
                if(isAdminPage) {       
                    <a href="/{bizUsername}"  class='btn btn-primary'>Preview as normal user {bizUsername}</a>
                } else {
                    <a href='/biz/bizUsername' class="btn btn-primary">Manage as {roleText}</a>
                }

            } else if(!loggedin.likes.contains(biz)) {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Like">Like</button>
            } else {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Like">Unlike</button>
            }           
    } else {
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Like">Log in to see good deals</button>
    }
}

<h1>@biz.name @renderRoleButton(loggedin, biz, isAdminPage)</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Note the changes to where the `@` character is in the first two lines and for `@value` (as serejja mentioned).

```
@reusableBlock(isAdmin: Boolean, value: String) = {
  @if(isAdmin){
    <a href="/admin/@value">@value</a>
  } else {
    <a href="/@value">@value</a>
  }
}
```

-EDIT-

Since you need to keep it as a `@{}` block then I think you'll need to concatenate Strings to build the HTML that you need. You'd just need to change those two lines inside the `isAdminPage` check. I think everything else can stay the same.

```
if(isAdminPage){
  Html("<a href=\"/" + bizUsername + "\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Preview as normal user " + bizUsername + "</a>")
}
```

Comment: Hi @estmatic, your solution works just fine for HTML block. However, as I want some scala variables inside the scala block to do some condition checking, I have to stick with the @{}. In my edited question, I am quite happy with this scala block except for the "if(isAdminPage)" checking part in which I cant output variable to HTML tag. Thanks for your answer. Appreciate that!

Comment: @Kabuky I updated my answer. I think you'll need to concatenate Strings to build the HTML you need inside that `if-else` block

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@reusableBlock(isAdmin: Boolean, value: String) = {
    @if(isAdmin){
        <a href="/admin/@value">@value</a>
    } else {
        <a href="/@value">@value</a>
    }
}
```